# Casual restaurant recommendations in Buenos Aires

Tags: restaurants, recommendations, buenos-aires

What places would you recommend for casual dining (not super fancy, but also not fast food)?

We will be staying in the Recoleta area, but will be exploring the city, so recommendations don't strictly have to be restricted to that area. I am interested in the sorts of places locals would recommend to each other rather than the standard tourist trap fare.

Comment: Hi Michael, you seem to have been here on Travel.SE for a while. Could you please try to make your question more specific? You've pretty much thrown open the whole city as scope and not specified a cuisine either (I'm assuming local). Try to add more detail about what you're looking for, as otherwise this question cannot have an answer that can be objectively chosen as correct. Until the edit, I'm afraid I need to close this question down.

Comment: Ankur, is there a way to turn this into a wiki question? I agree that it's not a question that lends itself well to a single authoritative answer, but at the same time, it is also the sort of question that is still highly valuable with a number of valid answers. Btw, I specifically don't have a particular part of the city or cuisine in mind since as a tourist I will be exploring the city and dining more than once, so a variety of recommendations is welcome.

Comment: As a side-note, I found this Yelp clone: http://www.znopit.com/ As of this writing, very few places reviewed there.

Comment: That's true. However, [community wiki questions are now discouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/). You're best bet at this would be try to use a local Brazilian search engine perhaps - whatever their equivalent of Google is. Maybe you can ask that question on WebApps.SE

Answer (score 2):

If you're in Recoleta, one place you should try is **El Cuartito** ("the small room") at [Talcahuano 937](http://g.co/maps/uff2h). When I was staying in that area, some local friends took me there, saying it's *the best* pizza place in the world. (They're rather serious about it too.) The place has been serving pizza since 1934, and while no longer just a small room (having been extended a few times), I believe the atmosphere and popularity is pretty much unchanged from those years.

[image]
[image]
<sup>Photos by yours truly</sup>

Most pizzas were ~ 30-70 $AR (April 2011). Quite different from pizza I'd had before, but great!

Of course, BA is *full* of really nice restaurants that still aren't "super fancy". In most places above all the beef dishes are great ([it's Argentina](http://idlewords.com/2006/04/argentina_on_two_steaks_a_day.htm), after all), and everything's very affordable taking the quality into account (well, at least if you're coming from Europe). I'll see if I find some notes of mine so I could name a few more restaurants...

Comment: A nice blog post about El Cuartito: [Eating Buenos Aires: Pizza, Fugazzetta & Empanadas at El Cuartito](http://eatlikeagirl.com/2011/06/13/eating-buenos-aires-pizza-fugazzetta-empanadas-at-el-cuartito/)

Comment: Is this a pizza on the photo?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for good budget restaurants (less than 7-8 USD per person) you have to go to the main center area ("La Valle" street) and you'll find tens of restaurants like that.

- In your area (La Recoleta) I know the restaurant "[Teatriz](http://www.teatrizrestaurante.com.ar/)" it serves european food but you can take a "Cordero Patagonico" (patagonic lamb) if you prefer an typical Argentinan dish. Is very elegant. Prices about 90-100 ARS. It's located in Riobamba 1220.
- If you prefer less elegant and 100% argentina food, a place where the locals go is 1800. It is cheaper than Teatriz, but absolutly recommandable. Is located in the cross between Rivadavia street with Brown street.
- The last one is in Puerto Madero, where most "modern" restaurants are. Here you can go to Fresh Market restaurant where you can take dishes about 30-40 ARS in a very good ambient.

In general, don't worry about restaurants. Buenos Aires is full of interesting places and is not expensive at all.

Note I'm talking about prices and resturants that I visited in 2008 and the prices and even the restaurants itselfs could be changed.